# How to convert PNG to TIF In Java Advanced Imaging

Tags: png, tiff, jai

I am trying to convert a PNG image to a TIF image.

I have tried the code below:

```
ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "TIF", new File("c:\\newFile.tif"));
```

and it does not work. I can use the same code and replace "TIF" with "jpg" to create a jpg but TIF does not work.  It looks like the ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames does not have a TIF writer. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Your code is correct. What you are missing, is a TIFF plugin for ImageIO. You can use JAI (`jai_imageio.jar`), [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/) (which is my own project) or other plugin. Usually (at least with JAI and TMI) , all you need is to add the required JARs  to the *run time* class path of your application, and the code/program you have will work (no need to recompile).

Comment: Thank you haraldK. Do you know of any other plugins beside the TwelveMonkeys?

Comment: Any reason you don't like to use either JAI or TwelveMonkeys? I'm sure you can find more using Google, but I believe these are the most widely used ones.